# Как засунуть установленный zabbix-server (db postgresql, web nginx) в docker?

Tags: postgresql, nginx, docker, zabbix

Установлен zabbix-server c базой postgresql и web nginx. Нужно это запихнуть в docker. Образ собирается. docker run -d -p 10052:10051 -v ${PWD}/etc/zabbix:/etc/zabbix:rw zabbix.test запускается. docker ps - тишина.
/home/dockershow$ docker logs c1d61781af41
zabbix_server [1]: cannot open config file "/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.local.conf": [2] No such file or directory.
Эта строчка в Dockerfile почему то не работает :
COPY ./zabbix_server.local.conf /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.local.conf
Вот мой Dockerfile:

````
# Ubuntu base image
FROM ubuntu:22.04


# Update packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y


# Install required packages
RUN apt-get install -y wget dpkg


# Install Zabbix repository
RUN wget https://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/6.0/ubuntu/pool/main/z/zabbix-release/zabbix-release_6.0-4+ubuntu22.04_all.deb \
    && dpkg -i zabbix-release_6.0-4+ubuntu22.04_all.deb


# Install Zabbix server package and set timezone
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y tzdata \
    && echo "Europe/Moscow" > /etc/timezone \
    && dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata \
    && apt-get install -y zabbix-server-pgsql


# Copy the Zabbix server config file
COPY ./zabbix_server.local.conf /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.local.conf


# Set the working directory to Zabbix config location
WORKDIR /etc/zabbix


# Expose the Zabbix server port
EXPOSE 10051


# Command to start Zabbix server
CMD [ "zabbix_server", "--foreground", "--config", "/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.local.conf" ]```
В zabbix_server.local.conf скопировал /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf
````